# The 4 screen orientations on Android

Tags: android, smartphone

There are 4 orientations on an Android device: portrait, landscape, reversePortrait, reverseLandscape. The difference between portrait and reversePortrait is obvious but I'm not sure about the landscape orientations. Is Landscape orientation a 90° right rotation or a 90° left rotation compared to Portrait orientation ? I know this is a stupid question but I can't find a clear answer to it.

Comment: Try it out by locking your app to one of the orientations, and you will see the result :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

portrait: Normal Device Poisition when you can see the Brand Logo Straight!

landscape: Tilt **top of the device** 90 degree to left from portrait Position

reversePortrait :Tilt **top of the device** 90 degree to left from landscape Position

reverseLandscape : Tilt **top of the device** 90 degree to left from reversePortrait Position

Answer (score 0):

Even if its not a popular question.But it has a spirit to be answered.
As per the global knowledge.
We know each and every monitors or screen's first pixel is starting from its upper left corner.(If the device is holded in an ordinary way).
As we take an X,Y graph we can conclude to this.(Based on screen resolution starting).
Portrait :- **180 degree**
Landscape :- **90 degree**